# TestFlight support for ios7 and older?

Tags: ios, testflight

TestFlight is scheduled to shutdown on Feb 26 of this year (2015). They have now set up testflight to work through the developer portal. However it looks like it may [only work for iOS8](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/).

```
TestFlight can be used to test iOS apps on iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch running iOS 8 or later.
```

Does this mean there will not be testflight support for ios7 or ios6? Previously I loved testflight because I don't own an ios6 device or every size of iphone, but I have friends that do that can test them for me.

Is there a solution for sending a beta app to someone that is running ios6 or 7 (or even ios5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We switched from TF to another solution once they annonced they were not going to support Android any more. And now I see clearly that it was a very right decision.

Going back to your question. No, they don't support any iOS version older than iOS 8. So there are no chances to test on iOS 7 or iOS6 with TestFlight.

However, there are lots of solutions that provide biuld distribution for iOS 7 and older. Here are three the most useful and stable:

1. Ubertesters ( http://ubertesters.com/ )
2. Applause ( http://www.applause.com/mobile-sdk )
3. HockeyApp ( http://www.hockeyapp.com/ )
4. Crachlitics ( https://try.crashlytics.com/ )

In our company we use Ubertesters today by 3 reasons:

- It supports Android and iOS 7;
- They have unique in-app bug submitionfeature which we were not able to fid anywhere else (you can make and edit screenshots of bug within the app)
- We use their beta testers.

However, it's a very personal point of view, so you might wish to make a quick research on all 4 solutions and find what exactly suits your development and testing needs.

Comment: Note: HockeyApp also comes with such a feedback feature, incl. screenshots and annotating. (Disclaimer: I am on of the founders)

Comment: @Kerni oh that's really nice! does hockeyapp allow to edit screenshots as well? I mean such editing features as marking, cropping, adding arrows and text, etc. Such features were not available last time when I tried your tool, so today it may differ from what I saw.

Comment: This blog post describes the features incl. some screenshots: http://hockeyapp.net/blog/2014/07/02/sending-images-and-screenshots.html

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding with testFlight no. Apple wants to shift all testings to iOS 8 on iTunesConnect

But you can use [Diawi](http://www.diawi.com/), it is a beta testing service that you can install the app with a link, but you still need to add the UUID's of the devices.

Answer (score 1):

http://fabric.io offers an ad-hoc distribution system for both iOS and Android. You'll still need to properly fill in the provisioning profile and sign the app with it, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **No**.

My assumption is that *Apple* wants app developers to drop **iOS 7** support. Because according to [Mixpanel's](https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_8/from_date:-140,report_unit:day,to_date:0) statistics regarding iOS 8 integration, there is ***%20*** usage of iOS 7 which I think is still ***huge***.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are other Beta Distribution plattforms, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28201240/4206060). 
I did have a good experience with Crashlytics so far ...

Comment: Crashlytics is awesome. However I have only used them for production apps.